# overflow with binary search recursively c++

Tags: c++, binary-search

I am trying to implement `binarySerach` recursively, but I got stack overflow.

First I have `find` function that takes 3 parameters. Then I call this function in `main` and pass adresess from the array. Nut I have got stack overflow!

```
bool find( const int x, const int* pBegin, const int* pEnd)
{    
    int medel =((*pBegin) + (*pEnd -1))/2 ;

    if(x == medel)
        return true ;

    else if( x<medel)
    {
        int last = medel -1 ;
        return find(x, pBegin, &last);
    }
    else if( x > medel) 
    {
        int begin = medel +1;
        return find(x, &begin, pEnd);
    }


}// find

void main()
{    
    int arr[10];
    for (int i=0;i<10;++i)
        arr[i] = i;
    bool found = find(3, &arr[0], &arr[10]);
    cout << "hittat = " << found << endl;

    system("pause");
}
```

Comment: There are several very fundamental issues around the use of pointers in your code.

Comment: Try debugging your problem by printing at entry to the find function the values of the pointers, the values in the range between the pointers (so you see where your search is) and key calculated values (like 'medel' in your case).

Answer (score 0):

There are several very fundamental issues around the use of pointers in your code. Without fixing the code for you, I'll give you a hint:

Try turning `medel` into *a pointer* to the middle element. This might help resolve some of the confusion.

Comment: But i cant calculate out medel from 2 pointers (pEnd, pBegin) in this case

Comment: You calculate the pointer to the middle element by adding half the distance between the range and end pointers. You can get an (integral) distance between pointers by subtraction.

Comment: You also have to make sure you only ever deal with pointers into your array. The distance is only well-defined, if the two pointers point into the same array. In your code &end and &begin obtain addresses of local automatic variables, which are completely unrelated to addresses within your array.